# Archive command missing in Outlook 2007, no Auto Archive shown

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, archiving

The Archive command is missing in Outlook 2007 from the File and Properties menus, and Auto Archive is not shown in the Options.

How can I turn it back on?

Comment: Is this computer part of a domain? And what operating system are you using (XP/Vista/7)?

Answer (score 1):

May be the reason of MS update KB 2412171. Please see this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2485531